# cant access my asset file in asset sub folder in react native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, react-native

i can access my **icon** if the folder in the root folder project,

example:

```
AwesomeProject v
  __test__ >
  android >
  icon >
  ios >
```

and i want to restructur my folder so i create new folder called **src** then i create sub folder called **assets** then put my **icon** there

example:

```
AwesomeProject v
  __test__ >
  android >
  ios >
  src v
    assets v
      icon >
```

this is my code in App.js file

```
<Image style={{ width: 26, height: 26 }} source={require('./src/assets/icon/home-active.png')} />
```

error message:
none of these file exist

*note: i have double checked to make sure im not typo

Answer (score 0):

you have to link your files so that they are added to the respective ios / android folders

structure:

```
AwesomeProject v
  __test__ >
  android >
  icon >
  ios >
```

Crete `react-native.config.js` file on root of your project

```js
  module.exports = {
    project: {
      ios: {},
      android: {},
    },
    assets: [
      './assets/icons/'
    ]
  }
```

now you will have to [link](https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking-libraries-ios#step-2) the files

```sh
yarn react-native link
```

or

```sh
npx react-native link
```

now you can check if the icons have been added to the folders of your ios / android application

Comment: after link the asset, how to call the icon is it like this `./src/assets/icon/home-active.png` ?

Comment: if you in android `/android/app/src/main/assets/your_folder/home-active.png`